# A target array with shape (32, 3) was passed for an output of shape (None, 15, 15, 3) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'animals/training_set',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical')

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'animals/test_set',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical')

cnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = 2, activation = 'relu', input_shape = [64, 
64, 3]))

cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2, strides = 2))

cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = 2, activation = 'relu', input_shape = [64, 
64, 3]))
cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size = 2, strides = 2))

cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))

cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 3, activation = 'softmax'))

cnn.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

cnn.fit(x = training_set, validatian_data = test_set, epochs = 15)
```

## The Following error pops out:

ValueError: A target array with shape (32, 3) was passed for an output of shape (None, 15, 15, 3) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a tf.keras.layers.Flatten layer after your last Maxpool2D in order to use the Dense layer on 1D data. Else, the Dense layers apply to 2D data which causes the mismatch.

Comment: Thank you very much for that help, you just saved me from having to code it through again for hours.

Answer (score 0):

In the second cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D()) function you must not pass the input shape. Input shapes are passed only for the first layer.

Comment: I also made a mistake on that, thank you very much for the help. Unfortunately I can't pick two correct answers.